# Unmet dependencies when trying to install GIMP

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dependencies

I got this error message when trying to install GIMP.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install python-minimal python2.7 python-tk python:any python-gtk2    
sudo aptitude install -f gimp
```

Using aptitude instead of apt may offer some automatic solutions for removing conflicting packages.